# How to make like this gradient sun effect using CSS?

Tags: css, radial-gradients

Is there a way to make gradient like this [image: originally at http://imgur.com/dA7RcsQ] with css only?

I've tried to use `background-position` tag

But it didn't work for me probably because I don't know how sprites work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a straightforward radial gradient. This should put you on the right track.

- `circle 150px` says it's a circular gradient with radius 150px
- `at 25% 33%` defines the origin (I've eyeballed it 1/4 from the left and 1/3 from the top) You can also use px or other lengths.
- Finally give the colors from the center out.

```css
div{
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle 150px at 25% 33%, white, yellow, lightyellow, aqua);
}
```

```html
  <div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Radial gradients are quite easy. Here's an example -

```
#gradient {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(60% 55%, farthest-side,blue,green,yellow,black); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-radial-gradient(60% 55%, farthest-side,blue,green,yellow,black); /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(60% 55%, farthest-side,blue,green,yellow,black); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at 60% 55%,blue,green,yellow,black); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Documentation here - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
three{
width:100%;
height:300px;
border:1px solid white;    
 background-image:radial-gradient( circle 80px at 25% 25% , rgb(255,255,255) 10%,rgba(251, 255, 185, .7), rgb(255,255,255) 60% 70%,rgb(2,153,218) 200%);}
```

If you want , change its position as your wish.